# Multiplication of a 3x3 matrix and a 3x1 vector

Tags: c++, arrays, calculator

My program requires a user to enter a 3 dimensional double vector v and a 3 x 3 double matrix M and the program will print out the matrix/vector product Mv. However I'm not getting a vector as my output, I'm getting a scalar. I'm not sure why, I've defined my output as a vector. Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    double v[3][1];
    double M[3][3];
    double Mv[3][1];
    int i,j;

    cout << "Enter in the components of the vector v:\n";

for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    cout << "Component " << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> v[i][0];
}

    cout << "Enter in the components of the 3 x 3 matrix M:\n";

for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        cin >> M[i][j];
    }
}   

for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    Mv[i][0]= 0.0;
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        Mv[i][0] += (M[i][j] * v[j][0]);
    }
}
cout << "The product of Mv is: " << Mv[i][0] << endl;   
return 0;
}
```

The code is printing the product as "1" - if I enter 1 for all elements of both vectors.

Comment: you print `Mv[4][0]` which is UB, you want to print `Mv[0][0]`, `Mv[1][0]`, `Mv[3][0]`.

Comment: `cout << "The product of Mv is: " << Mv[i][0] << endl;` is outside the loop, so all you are getting is `Mv[3][0]`. Move the line before the closing brace and it should work as expected

Comment: [OT]: What is the point of `double v[3][1]` whereas you can use `double v[3]` (and get rid of `[0]`) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are only printing the one value Mv[i][0] in the output call

you need to create a loop to print all the vector elements:

instead of:

```
cout << "The product of Mv is: " << Mv[i][0] << endl;
```

do:

```
cout << "The product of Mv is: [";

// start with the delimiter as a ',' but we need to change it 
// to ']' on the last iteration of the loop.
// so the result looks something like "[1.4,2.5,0.2]"
char delimiter = ',';

for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
   if (i == 2)
   {
      // on last loop iteration change delimiter to ']'
      delimiter = ']'
   }

   cout << Mv[i][0] << delimiter;
}

cout << endl;
```

Comment: You can merge this loop with your computation loop as Olia suggested.

Comment: Oh thanks, I did that. I knew I couldn't  put "The product of the matrix" in the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

Put `cout` one line above:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    Mv[i][0]= 0.0;
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        Mv[i][0] += (M[i][j] * v[j][0]);
    }
    cout << "The product of Mv is: " << Mv[i][0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: That will print the line The product of Mv is three times ;)

Comment: Well, `printf("Mv[%d][0] = %.3f\n", i, Mv[i][0]);` will look nicer. :)